# How to get supply levels of a printer via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, printing, cups

I'm trying to get the supply levels of a printer via the command line. So far I was able to get some information with a `lpoptions` (`marker-message` property) command. The problem is that the status of it doesn't update automatically. No matter how many pages I print the result of this command doesn't change.

At the same time, the standard UI (cmd+p) print utility of the macOS can get the proper information from the printer. I did a quick investigation and found out that it calls CUPS `ReportLevels` command.

So my question is: is there a way to call that `ReportLevels` command manually if so, how it can be done? Or maybe there is another way to force that refresh?

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What printer and what connection protocol?

Comment: It's a DS-RX1HS printer (http://dnpphoto.com/en-us/Products/Printers/ds-rx1hs). I'm not sure what protocol and how can I check it (I believe it's CUPS IPP implementation)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mistaken here, the `ReportLevels` command is an option used when configuring a printer in CUPS, which determines the level of detail to include in the printer's error log, it’s not used to get the current supply levels of a printer.

Also, `ReportLevels` is ***not*** a command that can be invoked manually from the command line.

Instead of that, you can use the `ReportLevels` option and another printer settings using the `cupsctl` command, which allows you to view and change various CUPS settings, including printer options and job limits. You can use the `-o` flag (followed by the option and it’s value) to modify the `ReportLevels` option<sup>1</sup>.

---

While the output of the `lpstat -t PRINTER-NAME | grep -E 'Toner Level|Ink Level'` command only displays the toner level for the specified printer (here named `PRINTER-NAME`), you can modify the command to display both the toner level and ink levels. Here's an example command that you can use to get the toner level and ink levels for a printer named `printer`:

```
lpstat -t printer | grep -E 'Toner Level|Ink Level|Ink Remaining'
```

This command includes the additional `| Ink Remaining` text in the `grep` command, which will match either `Ink Level` or `Ink Remaining` if either of those strings are present in the printer's information. This should allow you to capture the ink levels as well if they are available.

You should get something like this:

```
Toner Level: 64%
Ink Level: 83%
```

**Note:** Not all printers report ink levels and, even when they do, not all printer drivers support accessing those levels via the `lpstat` command. Therefore, it is possible that you may not see ink level information even if your printer supports it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For example, to set the `ReportLevels` option to `job,error`, you would use `cups to -o ReportLevels=job,error` (`sudo` might be required). This command will make it only log errors that occur during print jobs. Also, to get the current value of this command, just run `cupsctl | grep ReportLevels`.</sup>